# How can I collect forever in a Kotlin Flow to implement a retry mechanism?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor, kotlin-flow, ktor-client

I'm using kotlin flows to collect and emit from ktor websocet. I want to implement a retry mechanism when the `httpClient.webSocket` throws an exception. After that, I want to call `retryWith` function to create run the flow block again.

The real world scenario is this: When there is no internet connection. `httpClient.webSocket` throws an `UnresolvedAddressException` and retry block makes it try it three times. The user connects to internet and I call `retryWith` function. I want the flow block to run again. But since the flow is completed, `exceptionFlow` is not collected.

Here is what I've tried:

```kotlin
fun initConnection(scope: CoroutineScope) = flow {
        coroutineScope {
            val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
                // Catch the exception and emit it to the shared flow.
                println("*** emiting exception $exception")
                exceptionFlow.tryEmit(exception)
            }
            launch(exceptionHandler) {
                exceptionFlow.collect {
                    println("*** throwing $it")
                    throw it //throw here to trigger retry
                }
            }

            httpClient.webSocket(
                block = {
                    receiveAll {
                        emit(it)
                        handleIncoming(it)
                    }
                },
            )
        }
    }.retry(3) { cause ->
        println("*** retrying cause: $cause")
        connectionState = ConnectionState.RETRYING

        delay(500L)

        true
    }.catch {
        println("*** caught $it")
        connectionState = ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED
        emit(Incoming.Exception(it))
        close()
    }.onCompletion {
        println("*** onCompletion $it")
    }


suspend fun retryWith(throwable: Throwable) {
    exceptionFlow.emit(throwable)
}
```

How can I fix this? Maybe I need to suspend the flow forever somehow, but I'm not sure that's a good idea.

Comment: You can fix this by using the retryWhen operator instead of the retry operator. The retryWhen operator takes a predicate function as an argument. This predicate function is called whenever an exception occurs in the upstream flow. The predicate function should return true if the flow should be retried, and false if the flow should be completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Initial thoughts**

There are multiple "suspicious" parts in your code:

1. Using `CoroutineExceptionHandler` for controlling the logic of your service. I think this handler is more for cases like logging unhandled exceptions. Main way of reacting to exceptions is by using `try ... catch`.
2. Utilizing exceptions for signalling and controlling the flow of the application.
3. It feels strange that flow has side effects while being generated (`connectionState`, `close()`, `handleIncoming()`).
4. Each time we call `initConnection()` it starts a new flow, so we can potentially have multiple flows running at the same time. Then we call `retryWith()` on the singleton service, so does that mean it should retry all previously started flows? That feels strange. Maybe it would make more sense to create a single shared flow?
5. Sending events through flows and through callbacks (`retryWith()`) are two different approaches to the same problem. We can mix them, but it is usually better to use one pattern consistently. Maybe instead of calling `retryWith()` when the user connects to the internet, it would be better to expose an "internet connectivity state" flow and the above code would simply observe that flow?

Also, you didn't specify when exactly `retryWith()` can be called and what is your intended behavior in various cases. For example, if we are currently at the second retry, so it didn't yet switch to the disconnected state, is it possible `retryWith()` is called? If yes, should it be ignored and progress with the second retry or should it reset the retry counter?

**Answer**

One way to provide the restarting behavior for flows is by using functions like [flatMapConcat()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-concat.html), [flatMapLatest()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html), [transformLatest()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/transform-latest.html), etc. We create one flow for sending restart commands and we flat map each item into the flow which we intend to restart. Whenever we send an item in the first flow (restart command), it creates a new internal flow and downstreams its items:

```kotlin
restartFlow.flatMapLatest { createRestartableFlow() }
```

Depending on our case we could prefer to use  `flatMapConcat()` or `flatMapLatest()`. They differ in the behavior when we receive a restart command while the internal flow is still active. First function waits for the previously created internal flow to complete. Second cancels the previous flow and starts another one as soon as possible. Also, it probably makes sense to [conflate()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/conflate.html) the command flow, because usually when we receive multiple restart commands in a quick succession, we probably want to restart only once.

For signalling restarts we can use [MutableSharedFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow/), but because we have only a single consumer (I assume we call `initConnection()` only once or we use a shared flow), I think it makes more sense to use a conflated channel instead.

I may be unable to provide a fully working example for you. You may also need to fine-tune it for your specific needs. But it should be something along lines:

```kotlin
private val restartChannel = Channel<Unit>(Channel.CONFLATED)
    .also { it.trySend(Unit) } // we need one item initially to start straight away

fun initConnection() = restartChannel.consumeAsFlow().flatMapLatest {
    flow {
        httpClient.webSocket(
            block = {
                receiveAll {
                    emit(it)
                    handleIncoming(it)
                }
            },
        )
    }.retry(3) { cause ->
        println("*** retrying cause: $cause")
        connectionState = ConnectionState.RETRYING

        delay(500L)

        true
    }.catch {
        println("*** caught $it")
        connectionState = ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED
        emit(Incoming.Exception(it))
        close()
    }.onCompletion {
        println("*** onCompletion $it")
    }
}

fun retry() {
    // Conflated channel never suspends and is guaranteed to succeed.
    restartChannel.trySend(Unit)
}
```

Please be aware I didn't at all test this code as it is hard without the working websocket part.

Comment: Hey @broot, thanks for your answer. I wasn't working for a while and now I'm back. Bounty has expired at that time but I will definitely reward the answer if it works for me. I call retry when a message should be sent through websocket and connection is not established due to an exception. I tried your solution but I get JobCancellationException after calling retry. Why do you think it is?

Comment: looks like close function was closing the job so webSocket threw that error. Your answer was very guiding. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Side note: your function returns a cold flow, so it's inappropriate for it to take a CoroutineScope as a function parameter. Currently you haven't tried to use this scope anyway.

A couple of approaches:

1. Wrap it in another flow block that collects it in a loop:

```
fun initConnection(scope: CoroutineScope) = flow {
        //...
    } //...
    .catch {
        // ...
    }
    .let { flow { while(true) emitAll(it) } }
    .onCompletion {
        println("*** onCompletion $it")
    }
```

2. This feels a little hacky since you would be using an Exception for a non-exceptional case, but you could create an Exception type for the success case and throw it in `onCompletion`, and then tack on a `retryWhen` that retries when that successful exception is thrown.

Comment: I was actually using the scope to turn it into a SharedFlow. (Although I'm not sure I need to) I forgot to remove it for the question. 1st approach made the flow run forever but always retries due to JobCancellationException. I actually don't want it to retry without calling my retryWith function.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at the internals of your flow at all, but that looks suspicious. First, the interior `coroutineScope` block is unnecessary because the `flow` block already includes a coroutine scope receiver. It seems weird to be catching exceptions in a separate launch block and rethrowing them plus publishing them elsewhere. I don't have any ktor experience.

Comment: Ktor doesn't matter here actuallly. interior `coroutineScope` was necessary because I had to start a coroutine scope to collect from the exception flow. It could not be different scope, it has to be in the same scope. Throwing on the same scope would cause it to run retry block. I just wanted to retry the flow block from outside of this function. There might be better ways then catching exceptions and rethrowing them, but it works. The only thing that doesn't work is the flow that ends. I wanted it to suspend so emiting an exception would be possible at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can call
Retry the httpClient.webSocket call multiple times if it fails.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*

private const val MAX_RETRIES = 3

fun webSocketFlow(): Flow<Unit> = flow {
    var retryCount = 0

    while (retryCount < MAX_RETRIES) {
        try {
            //Websocket logic

            httpClient.webSocket {
                
            }

           
            break
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            retryCount++
            if (retryCount >= MAX_RETRIES) {
                // Return the error, then collector can handle it.
                emitAll(flowOfError(e))
            } else {
                delay(1000) // Delay before retrying
            }
        }
    }
}

fun <T> flowOfError(error: Throwable): Flow<T> = flow {
    throw error
}

val exceptionFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Throwable>()

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val job = launch {
        webSocketFlow()
            .catch { e -> exceptionFlow.emit(e) }
            .collect {
                // Handle collected items as per your need.
            }
    }

    exceptionFlow.collect { e ->
        // Handle error here
        println("Caught exception: $e")

        
        retryWith(job)
    }
}

fun retryWith(job: Job) {
    if (job.isActive) {
        job.cancel()
    }
    // Restart the job or create a new flow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by using the **retryWhen** operator instead of the **retry** operator. The **retryWhen** operator takes a predicate function as an argument. This predicate function is called whenever an exception occurs in the upstream flow. The predicate function should return **true** if the flow should be retried, and **false** if the flow should be completed.

```
fun initConnection(scope: CoroutineScope) = flow {
    coroutineScope {
        val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
            // Catch the exception and emit it to the shared flow.
            println("*** emiting exception $exception")
            exceptionFlow.tryEmit(exception)
        }
        launch(exceptionHandler) {
            exceptionFlow.collect {
                println("*** throwing $it")
                throw it //throw here to trigger retry
            }
        }

        httpClient.webSocket(
            block = {
                receiveAll {
                    emit(it)
                    handleIncoming(it)
                }
            },
        )
    }
}.retryWhen { cause ->
    println("*** retrying cause: $cause")
    connectionState = ConnectionState.RETRYING

    delay(500L)

    //cause is UnresolvedAddressException && retries < MAX_RETRIES
}.catch {
    println("*** caught $it")
    connectionState = ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED
    emit(Incoming.Exception(it))
    close()
}.onCompletion {
    println("*** onCompletion $it")
}
```